# create multiple transactions between two accounts using SendTransactionAsync method nethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, nethereum

I am trying to create multiple transactions between two accounts using SendTransactionAsync method. But I am getting "replacement transaction underpriced" message. I found some links which says we need to increase nonce to create new transactions in loop. But I am not able to find Nethereum function where I can mention nonce value while creating transaction. Can anybody guide me with solution to this?

```
HexBigInteger gas = new HexBigInteger(25000);
HexBigInteger value = new HexBigInteger(100);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
  gas = new HexBigInteger(gas.Value + (gas.Value * 20) / 100);
  value = new HexBigInteger(value.Value + (value.Value * 20) / 100);
  var privateKey1 = "0x5083ff34a6610ad0d08d5e568fcee84e29a1391a6fffa8cf96484388f57de731";
  var account = new Account(privateKey1);
  var web3 = new Web3(account, "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", null, null);
  var addressTo = "0x12890D2cce102216644c59daE5baed380d84830c";
  string data = "ASDF";
  var transaction = await web3.TransactionManager.SendTransactionAsync(new TransactionInput(data.ToHexUTF8(), addressTo, account.Address,gas, value));
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create your web3 instance outside loop and give a try